# Ruby poor performance on algorithm to calculate moving average (compared to java)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I made this algorithm to find when the Standard deviation became smaller than the average for a set of values, by increasing the order of a moving average.
Typically my data has about 300 values, mostly zeros, and the order of the moving average that meets the criteria is about 50.

The problem is that i already have this same algorithm in java and it runs in a few seconds (less than 5), and in ruby it takes about 3 to 5 minutes.

As I'm new to ruby on rails, I may be doing some foolish that compromise the performance.

So, is there anyway to improve this in ruby on rails? If not, how come java calculate this 100x faster? Since i'm using ruby on rails with postgresql, should i build this function on PL/pgSQL?

Here's the algorithm:

```
while mvg_avg<mvg_st_dev do
      freq_on+=1 #fre_on = the order of the moving average
      values = Array.new(date_value.count-freq_on+1, Float(0)) #date_value is the original array with the values. 
      sum_values = 0 #sum_values will be used to calculate the average

      #here i will build the new array, with the moving average values, and then i calculate the new total average for this new array.
      for i in 0..(date_value.count-1-freq_on+1)
        for j in i..(i+freq_on-1) #go through the date(i) until date(i+order-1) 
          values[i]+= date_value[j]
        end
        values[i]=values[i]/freq_on
        sum_values+=values[i]
      end

      mvg_avg = sum_values / values.size.to_f

      #now i find out the standard deviation
      sumSt=0
      values.each do |value|
        sumSt+=(value-mvg_avg)**2
      end
      mvg_st_dev=Math.sqrt(sumSt/date_value.count)

    end
```

**UPDATE 2018-02-07 #1**
Keyword that was causing all this trouble: Casting.

My array with the data were mostly Integer values, and inside the loops they were been used as float. Once that I built my data as Float before entering the loops, the code run only about 10x slower than Java (witch is acceptable, as Tadman commented that ruby math runs about this slower than Java).

Here is where i'm build my data:

```
  def self.pushProductValuesToArray(dates, hashDps)
    date_value = Array.new
    dates.each do |date|
      dp = hashDps[date]
      date_value.push (dp.nil? ? 0.0 : dp.value.to_f) #here i was pushing integers to the array, instead of float.
    end
    return date_value
  end
```

Comment: while it might be the case that it's magnitutes slower, it's quite unlikely. but since you did not give a complete code example it's rather hard to do anything with your code.

Comment: Maybe better asked on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) since the code is functional and you are looking for improvements

Comment: @engineersmnky The main purpose of the post is to discuss the performance of Ruby vs. Java, and there may be nothing wrong with the code. (Nothing jumps out at me, at least.)

Comment: @Roger I'd be curious to see how the performance on JRuby would compare. Could you try it and let us know?

Comment: @KeithBennett the questions asked *"So, is there anyway to improve this in ruby on rails? ... Since i'm using ruby on rails with postgresql, should i build this function on PL/pgSQL?"* sound like code review to me thus the suggestion as it might get better traction there. If there was something wrong with the code it would actually fit better on SO then it being functional

Comment: @engineersmnky I reread the question, and I think you're right -- and I am too. He also says "If not, how come java calculate this 100x faster? Since i'm using ruby on rails with postgresql, should i build this function on PL/pgSQL?"; both of which would not benefit from a code review. But he did invite a code review as you say.

Comment: Seeing `for` in Ruby code is usually a sign things aren't really Ruby. That keyword is hardly ever used since `x.each` is preferable. You'll also want to use `underscore_style` variables as capital letters have significant meaning in Ruby and are reserved for `ClassName` and `CONSTANT_NAME` situations.

Comment: Is `date_value.count` an expensive operation? If that involves a database call it'd explain why it's brutally slow.

Comment: Where is the Java code?

Comment: Data for testing would also be helpful.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you have an array `arr`, do you want to determine the smallest `n` such that, for `a = arr[0,n]`, the standard deviation of the elements of `a` is smaller than the mean of those elements? On the other hand, given your reference to moving averages of "order" `m`, do you want to determine the smallest `n >= m` such that, for `b = arr[n-m,n]`, the standard deviation of the elements of `b` is smaller than the mean of those elements?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using primitives in Java (float, double rather than Float, Double, for example), then this could explain it. Java primitives are very fast because they are not objects and are optimized for speed. In Ruby, everything is an object that needs to be created; and I'm pretty sure all Ruby objects are stored on the heap and not the stack, so memory allocation takes time, as opposed to the Java primitives that may live on the stack.

I know nothing in Ruby on Rails that would improve performance of mathematical calculations, and my guess is that using the data base for this kind of thing would perform very poorly.

Comment: Ruby numbers are objects, just as everything is in Ruby, but they're not normal objects, they're not heap allocated, they're just a pointer with some magic bits sprinkled in. Math in Ruby is slower, that much is undeniable, but only by a factor of 8-10x. That can't account for the wild difference in performance which here seems to be 200x or more.